# Why am I unable to use try-except to convert str to int?

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, type-conversion, try-except

I did these two different sets of code that does the same function on tkinter. The simplediaglog version works just fine but I wanted to use entry (because I want to display the output on the same pop-up window), which does not work.

The problem lies mainly in multiplying a list of float values in a dictionary to the entry input value and getting python to even recognise the entry input as int.

I tried restructuring the try-except-else, tried using different ways to convert the entry input to integer using IntVar(). I also tried indexing the dictionary i.e. x[y][0]. I tried putting the float values into string e.g. x = {"A": "2.3", "B": "0.3"}. But nothing works, keep getting different errors but all boils down to one thing: unable to multiply integer/str with float values from dictionary.

```py
def p(y):
    while True:
        Q = simpledialog.askstring("test", "Enter number:")
        try:
            Q = int(Q)
            if Q is None:
                break
            elif Q <=0 or Q> 10:
                raise ValueError
            else:
                W = str(round(Q * x[y], 1))  # Round off to 1 d.p
                messagebox.showinfo("test", "Ans is\n" + W + " minute(s)")
                break
        except:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "enter a value from 0 to 10")
        break
```

This code works and showed everything correctly.

BTW, for below code, the place geometry is something I put randomly to see if overall code works, I don't think the error is due to the geometry.

The above simpledialog code works.

However, this entry widget code does not:

```py
def p(y):
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Average Waiting Time")
    root.geometry("800x500")

    Label(root, text="Enter number of people: ").place(x=20, y=30)
    Q = Entry(root, bd =5)
    Q.place(x=220, y=30)

    def B():
        Q_input = Q.get()
        while True:
            try:
                int(Q_input)
                if Q_input is None:
                    continue
                elif Q_input <=0 or Q_input > 10:
                    raise ValueError
                else:               
                    W = str(round(Q_input * x[y], 1))  # Round off to 1 d.p
                    Label(root, "Ans\n" + W + " minute(s)").place(x=50, y=500)

            except:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "enter a value from 0 to 10")

            break   

    ok = Button (root, text="OK", command = B)
    ok.place(x=300, y=300)

    cancel = Button (root, text="Cancel", command = root.destroy)
    cancel.place(x=400,y=300)

    root.mainloop()
```

This is my dictionary for the list of float values:

```py
x = {"A": 0.8, "B": 2.5, "C": 1.2}
```

I expect to see a label with something like Ans 2.3 minute(s) appearing in the same window as the entry widget.

But even if I key in an int such as '5' into the entry input, the try-except does not convert it to int because I keep getting the "Error" message: "enter a value from 0 to 10".

Why is this so? Is it because it is an entry widget and not simpledialog because it worked for simplediaglog?

Also, even when I got to the line for W (manage to convert Q_input) to integer, it shows error: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'.

My main question is why the float dictionary list (and type conversion from str to int) is able to register with simpledialog but not for entry widget? What is the difference? Is it possible to multiply float values from dictionary with an integer from entry input?

Also, are there any other methods to display the output on the same pop-up window besides entry widget?

Thank you in advance!

Edit:
So, I tried converting Q_input to int before while loop and printing it. 
If I key in '5', it prints '5'. I know it did convert to int because when I input 'hi', there is an error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hi'.

I changed `int(Q_input)` to `Q_input=int(Q_input)` too. Per suggestion, I also changed `continue` to `break` under `if Q_input is None:`.

But, the try-except still does not work, it did not even try converting Q_input to int, it simply skipped straight to `except`.

Sorry for asking so many questions, so I will just sum it up into one question:
Is my `try-except` code not working because of differences between simpledialog and entry widget, if so what is the reason and if not why is the code not working then?

**Solution:** 
I realised something , all along I had not been able to display the label because of this: `Label(root, "Ans\n" + W + " minute(s)").place(x=50, y=500)`. I did not put `text=`, haha I was able to show the label successfully after adding `text=`. My bad, so all along the problem was not converting the entry input to integer. There is a need to change `int(Q_input)` to `Q_input=int(Q_input)` though. I just sort of jump to the conclusion that the error was because of type conversion because the programme kept going straight to `except`.

Comment: I down voted because there seems to be [too much code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/) and [too much information](https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchinfo/) and too many questions in one. Please refocus your post a little bit:)

Comment: I up voted because it makes sense if you actually read the post.  Can you print out the value of Q_input and convert Q_input to a int before entering the While True loop? Also print that out and see what you get.

Comment: @Yepram Yeransian  Thanks for the suggestion. I convert and printed Q_input before the `while True` loop. If I key in '5', it prints '5'. I know it did convert to int because when I input 'hi', there is an error . However, the `try-except` still does not work, everything just goes to the `except` part.

Comment: @ Corentin Pane  Hi, sorry for making it seems messy, but I posted so much code because the question I really wanted to ask is:  "Is my try-except code not working because of differences between simpledialog and entry widget, if so what is the reason and if not why is the code not working then?".  So, I sort of need to post both code because I am comparing between simpledialog and entry widget. I created an account just for this ques because I really cannot figure it out. I am sorry if I did something outside of protocol - am I suppose to comment back or edit my ques - for this website.

Comment: As Q_input is a string when the elif clause is executed `Q_input <=0 or Q_input > 10` raises a `TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` in the try: block.  Therefore it runs the except: block and prints the error message.

Comment: @TlsChris  Any suggestions on how to do that? because `Q_input=int(Q_input)` did not work.

Comment: `Q_input=int(Q_input)` did work in the end, I just did not realise I did not put `text=` in `Label(root, "Ans\n" + W + " minute(s)").place(x=50, y=500)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use a function to safely convert a string to an int or a float, e.g. `to_int` below.

The code below creates an answer Label that's used as required.  The original code created a label for every click of the button.

```
from tkinter import *

def to_int(string, fail = 0):
    try: 
        return int(string)
    except ValueError:
        return fail

x = {"A": 0.8, "B": 2.5, "C": 1.2}

def p(y):
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Average Waiting Time")
    root.geometry("800x500")

    Label(root, text="Enter number of people: ").place(x=20, y=30)
    Q = Entry(root, bd =5)
    Q.place(x=220, y=30)

    answer = StringVar()
    answer.set("")
    Label(root, textvariable = answer ).place(x=50, y=500)

    def B():
        Q_input = Q.get()

        v = to_int(Q_input, -1)
        # Returning <0 triggers the error message

        if v <=0 or v > 10:
            answer.set("Enter a value from 0 to 10")
        else:               
            W = str(round(v * x[y], 1))  # Round off to 1 d.p
            answer.set("Ans\n" + W + " minute(s)")
            print(answer.get())

    ok = Button (root, text="OK", command = B)
    ok.place(x=300, y=300)

    cancel = Button (root, text="Cancel", command = root.destroy)
    cancel.place(x=400,y=300)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I realised something though, all along I had  not been able to display the label because of this: `Label(root, "Ans\n" + W + " minute(s)").place(x=50, y=500)`. I did not put `text=`, haha I was able to show the label successfully after adding `text=`. My bad, so all along the problem was not converting the entry input to integer. I just sort of jump to the conclusion that the error was because of that because the programme kept going straight to `except`.

Answer (score 2):

You dont actually save the integer conversion:

```
try:
            Q_input = int(Q_input)
```

also

```
except Exception as e:
 print(e)
```

so you know what is going wrong if the exception is triggered

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed `int(Q_input)` to `Q_input = int(Q_input)` but the `try-except` still does not work. (I think I put `Q_input = int(Q_input)` at first but after trying various ways, it got shortened haha.)

Comment: When I tried it on my end it still failed, yes, but for a different reason now.
I recommend, for every "Except" that you have in your code, do this:

except Exception as e:
 print(e)
 Or add "e" to the messagebox output.
Then it will tell you what the problem is. Previously it was that str and int cannot be compared with >=, now it should be a different problem.

Answer (score -1):

This is the issue it seems.

```
try:
    int(Q_input)
    if Q_input is None:
        continue
```

You need to assign int(Q_input) into a variable just like you did in your working code. See below.

```
try:
    Q = int(Q)
    if Q is None:
        break
```

Comment: This has the exact same problem. You're trying to convert `Q` to an integer before checking that it is `None`. The check needs to happen before trying to convert, since the conversion will fail if `Q` is `None`. Also, `int()` will never return `None`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The `try-except` is still not working though.  The problem is that the `try-except` did not even 'try', it just skipped straight to 'except'. I had tried various methods before finally asking this question and I managed to get to the line for `W = str(round(Q_input * x[y], 1))` but only by using `try-except-else` whereby I placed this particular line in to the `else` block. However, there is still an error: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'. The weird thing is all these worked for simpledialog but somehow does not for entry widget.

Comment: @BryanOakley   So, I should put `if Q is None` under `except:` then? I see what is wrong with putting `None` there under `try` but I am curious as to why it worked for the simpledialog code? Anyways, I removed that  whole if  `if Q is None:`, but the `try-except` still does not work, the output goes straight to `except:`.